# Azeroth Core Log System

Tags: azerothcore

I am having an issue, i cannot log my chat in game, whispers, announcements.

```
Appender.chat.system=2,2,15,chat/chatplayers_%s.log

Logger.chat.system=3,Console Server
```

everything else logs correct except  the chat, Same settings are on all my appends.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out, in order to correctly  append the chat log the following setting needs to be set in your worlserver.conf. That will create a file chat*.* with a time stamp!

```
Appender.Chat=2,2,9,Chat%s.log,a

Logger.chat.log=2,Chat
```